# INSERT statement error - MySQLdb/Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have the following code:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO term_results(%s, %s) VALUES (%s, %s) WHERE results_id = %s", (term, termInserted, nResult, bResult, mostRecentRecord))
```

`term` and `termInserted` are both strings. The rest are integers. I get the following error:

`Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

I have tried rearranging the `WHERE` clause but no luck, can you help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `where` with the `values` form of `insert`.  Just use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO term_results(%s, %s)
    SELECT %s, %s
    from <somewhere>
    WHERE results_id = %s"
```

I don't know what the expression `(term, termInserted, nResult, bResult, mostRecentRecord)` is supposed to be doing.  You also need a `from` name with a table that has a column called `results_id`.

If the list are actually more columns, then perhaps you want something like this:

```
INSERT INTO term_results(%s, %s, term, termInserted, nResult, bResult, mostRecentRecord)
    SELECT %s, %s, term, termInserted, nResult, bResult, mostRecentRecord
    from <somewhere>
    WHERE results_id = %s"
```

Comment: Basically I have a table and in it is a record already inserted into handled by prior code (omitted here) but all the columns are NULL except for the `results_id` column (which is the PK and unique for each record). I run some code before the above (again, omitted here) to find the most recent record (there is also a timestamp column (specifically for this purpose)) and return the `results_id` integer into a variable `mostRecentRecord` so that I can UPDATE the record (perhaps an UPDATE statement required?) with the new information in the other variables.

Comment: @I_lost_my_last_account . . . Yes, you make a reasonable observation.  If you want to update a record, then you need to use `update`.  You might consider deleting this question and asking another with a more complete set of information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139423/update-statement-error-mysqldb-python