# UPDATE statement error - MySQLdb/Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm testing an UPDATE statement on an existing record in my test table. It looks like this:

```
term = 'example-column'
termInserted = term + '_inserted'
mostRecentRecord = 6
nResult = 777
bResultsInserted = 77

#print(termInserted)
cur.execute("UPDATE `term_results` SET `%s` = %s, `%s` = %s WHERE `results_id` = %s", (term, nResult, termInserted, bResultsInserted, mostRecentRecord))
connectToDb.commit()
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

`Error 1054: Unknown column ''example-column'' in 'field list'`

Which I can't understand because the column does exist by that name. Can you help? Thanks.

Comment: Also - when I run the equivalent SQL statement in PHPMyAdmin, it works as expected.

Comment: Please add the schema output from "EXPLAIN term_results"

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The code should look like:

```
cur.execute("""UPDATE `term_results` SET `%s` = %s, `%s` = %s WHERE `results_id` = %s""" % (term, nResult, termInserted, bResultsInserted, mostRecentRecord))
```